# Show a facebook page in another site as iframe in another site

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to show a facebook page as iframe in another site?

Comment: I tried with <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"> but it throws an error. Not sure why but I think facebook does restrict the usage of iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops! It seem unreachable. You can read the part of the article about "X-Frame-Options" [1]: http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking